# Why there is a difference in output of argc?

Tags: c++, linux, g++

Why there is a difference in output of argc below?

First :

```
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<iostream>
int main(int argc,char *argv[])
{
  for(int i=1;i<=argc;i++)
    std::cout<<argv[i]<<"\n"<<std::endl;
  std::cout<<argc<<std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

I get the output for argv however i do not get output for argc.

Second case :

```
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<iostream>
int main(int argc,char *argv[])
{
  std::cout<<argc<<std::endl;
  for(int i=1;i<=argc;i++)
    std::cout<<argv[i]<<"\n"<<std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

I get output for both argv and argc.

In both cases if I use "printf" instead of "cout" I get output for argc.

Why there is a difference in output of argc?

Comment: `i<=argc` leads to undefined behavior. If `argc` is 2, then the valid `argv` indexes are `argv[0]` and `argv[1]`. `argv[2]` is undefined behavior.

Comment: It just happens that the `std::cout` mechanism gets confused, since you access `argv[argc]` in your code. If you run `fprintf(stdout, "%d\n", argc);` before your `std::cout<<argc<<std::endl;`, perhaps you could get the value of `argc` (as it happens for me). In any case: always `< argc`, like others told you.

Answer (score 3):

The behaviour of your code in both cases is *undefined*. You need to replace `i<=argc` with `i < argc`.

By the C++ standard `argv[argc]` is `nullptr`. *Don't* try to dereference that.

Answer (score 2):

It's specified by both the C++ specification and POSIX that `argv[argc]` will always be a null pointer. You attempt to dereference that null pointer when you use `<=` in the loop condition.

When you dereference a null pointer you will have [*undefined behavior* (or UB)](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub). It usually leads to a *crash*. The `printf` function usually have a check for null pointer strings and prints `"(null)"`, but it's still UB.

Comment: in the first case i have used the "cout for argc" outside the "for loop". the loop is without {} so just one statement below that is considered. it works perfectly for "printf"

Comment: @varun Updated my answer.